# How to make varibale with values from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove .html from array values and how to put that vaules in a varibale like (newvalue) from array.I tried many times but not working.If you know please resolve this issue.I am getting confusion.How to get the values using below the codes.

```
    var arr="tree1.html,tree2.html,tree3.html";
    namesonly(arr);
    function namesonly(arr){
    var newvalue;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ 
    newvalue=arr[i].remove('.html');
    } 
    return newvalue;
    } 
    //results should be like this newvalue = "tree1,tree2,tree3";
```

Comment: `newvalue=arr[i].replace('.html', '');`

Comment: @gugateider - `arr` is not an array.

Comment: first of all `var arr="tree1.html,tree2.html,tree3.html";` is not an array, so you can't iterate over it.

Comment: true hadn't noticed. Split the string first then.
`arr = arr.split(","); then the code`

Comment: jQuery `remove` method is for removing DOM elements, it won't work with strings.

Comment: Do this: `let newValues = arr.replace(/.html/g, '')` on line two. None of the other code is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your string, then create new array (`newvalues` instead of `newvalue`). Then you can use `substring (0, arr[i],length-5)` and add that to the array with `array.push`. This will remove the last 5 characters (i.e. ".html")

```
var arr="tree1.html,tree2.html,tree3.html";
namesonly(arr);

function namesonly(arr){
arr = arr.split(",");
var newvalues = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ 
newvalues.push(arr[i].substring(0, arr[i].length-5));
} 
return newvalues;
}
```

Comment: Getting Error [object Promise] : I have changed like this: var arr="tree1.html,tree2.html,tree3.html";

const namesonly=asyn(arr)=>{
arr = arr.split(",");
var newvalues = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ 
newvalues.push(arr[i].substring(0, arr[i].length-5));
} 
return newvalues;
} 

console.log(  namesonly(arr)  )

Comment: @Sitharth it seems like you are just printing out the return value for namesonly, which is now a promise. You should await the promise and get then get the promise value

Comment: @Sitharth The original question has been answered. If you have a follow up question, you should post it on SO

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a Regular Expression in the `replace()` function. Your goal can be reached with a single statement.

You could change your code to this:

```js
var arr="tree1.html,tree2.html,tree3.html";
let newValues = arr.replace(/.html/g, '');
console.log(newValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things wrong here, but the first and biggest is that your array is **not actually an array**. It's a string (aka text), because its surrounded by quotes `" "`.

In JavaScript arrays look like this:

```
var array = [ element1, element2, element3 ];
```

and strings look like this:

```
var string = "text1234.,!?/";
```

Arrays have to be surrounded by braces `[]` and the elements are separated by a comma `,`. Strings are always surrounded by quotes `""` and any characters inside (like your commas) are treated the same as normal letters or numbers or other text.

If you want to store your filenames in an array, you'll have to use braces and put the comma *outside* the pairs of quotes, like:

```
var arr = [ "tree1.html", "tree2.html", //etc...
```

**But** this wont do what you want either, because the `remove()` function you are using doesn't do what you think, either. It removes an element if that **entire element** matches what you input. Since you dont have any elements that are just `".html"` without any other text, nothing will be removed.

Instead you should use one of the many functions for editing strings (`substring()`, `slice()`, and `replace()` could all be useful for you).

**But** even then it *still* wont work, because your variable `var newvalue` is **also not an array**. To use it as an array you must first initialize it with:

```
var newvalue = [];
```

and then add elements with:

```
newvalue.push(element);
```

This method will work, *however* I recommend looking up how to use `array.forEach()` or `array.map()` because either of those would be more suited to your goal here and more useful in the future. Good luck!